# This torch project keep telling me "Expected 2 or more dimensions (got 1)"

Tags: python, pytorch

I was trying to make my own neural network using PyTorch. I do not understand why my code is not working properly.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optimizers
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import os
import hashlib

# Only for the first time
MAKE_DATA = False


class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 100)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 200)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(200, 200)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(200, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return F.relu(x)


def make_numirical(data):
    data = str(data)
    data = data.encode()
    data = hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()
    str1 = ''
    for c in data:
        if not (c >= '0' and c <= '9'):
            c = ord(c)
            if c > 10:
                c /= 10
        str1 += str(int(c))
    return int(str1[:20])


def make_train_data():
    HITS = 'Songs_DB/Hits'
    NOHITS = 'Songs_DB/NoHits'
    hits_count = 0
    no_hits_count = 0
    LABELS = {HITS: 0, NOHITS: 0}
    training_data = []
    i = 0
    for label in LABELS:
        for f in tqdm(os.listdir(label)):
            try:
                path = os.path.join(label, f)
                with open(path, 'rb') as file:
                    data = file.read()
                    file.close()
                data = make_numirical(data)
                data = int(data)
                training_data.append([np.array([data]), np.eye(2)[i]])

                if label == HITS:
                    hits_count += 1
                else:
                    no_hits_count += 1
            except:
                pass
        i += 1

        np.random.shuffle(training_data)
        np.save('training_data.npy', training_data)
        print(hits_count)
        print(no_hits_count)


if MAKE_DATA:
    make_train_data()

model = Model()

# 1 = brown, 0 = not brown, 1 = cat, 0 = dog.

Xs = torch.Tensor([[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0]])
ys = torch.Tensor([[1], [0], [0], [1], [0], [1], [0], [1], [1]])

i = 0
for x in Xs:
    output = model(x)
    print(output)
    loss = F.nll_loss(output, ys[i])

print(loss)
```

The program keeps giving me this error:

> Expected 2 or more dimensions (got 1)

Can anyone explain what is wrong with my code?

Comment: [`nn.Linear()`][https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html] has an implicit batch size dimension, so the input should be of shape (batch_size,2) . In your case, you loop over every data point individually, that means batch_size=1. Try to reshape your input `x.reshape((1,2))` or pass the whole tensor `Xs` as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensor you use as the dataset, `Xs` is shaped `(n, 2)`. So when looping over it each element `x` ends up as a 1D tensor shaped `(2,)`. However, your module expects a batched tensor as input, *i.e.* here a 2D tensor shaped `(n, 2)`, just like `Xs`. You have two possible options, either use a data loader and divide your dataset into *batches*, or unsqueeze your input `x` to make it two dimensional shaped `(1, 2)`.

- Using a [`TensorDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.TensorDataset) and wrapping it with a [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader):

  ```
  >>> dataset = TensorDataset(Xs, ys)
  >>> dataloader = Dataloader(dataset, batch_size=4)
  ```

  Then iterating over `dataloader` will return batches of fours (inputs and corresponding labels):

  ```
  >>> for x, y in dataloader:
  ...     output = model(x)
  ...     loss = F.nll_loss(output, y)
  ```

  `TensorDataset` and `Dataloader` are both imported from [`torch.utils.data`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html).
- Or use [`torch.Tensor.unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html) on `x` to add one extra dimension:

  ```
  >>> for x, y in zip(Xs, ys):
  ...     output = model(x.unsqueeze())
  ...     loss = F.nll_loss(output, y)
  ```

  Alternatively, you can do `x[None]` which has the same effect.

Comment: Thank you very much, the explanation was great!